# Yii - setdefault in form from GET

Tags: php, yii

I have a link:

http://mywebsiteonyii.com/article/new/number/3

In my database I have:

id | title | body | number

I can make a form from this, but how do I hide $form['number'] in the template and set the default from this URL (parameter number)?

Answer (score 0):

> default from this URL (parameter number)?

if i got you correct you intend to redirect this form to some action. If yes then you can use

```
'action'=>yii::app->createUrl('actiontogo','id'=>'yourparameter')
```

for ex

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'user-form',
        'action'=>yii::app->createUrl('addUser','id'=>$model->id),
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```

if i did not understood please make comment and describe your problem more clearly

Good Luck

Comment: i would like save number to database without render input for this. Should save from URI (parameter number)